How to make a variable hold a pipeline build ID, or default to its latest build
I am currently working on a Azure pipeline that grabs an artifact from another pipeline. Currently, there is a variable set called artifactBuildId that holds the build ID of the run the user would want to grab the artifact from. However, I would like to make it so that, if the variable is never set (so it would be empty), it defaults to grabbing the latest build of the pipeline. Any ideas of where to start with this?
I don't have much experience with Azure pipelines. I was trying to understand how to grab the latest build. But doing it for a different pipeline, using an if-else statement, and setting a predefined variable didn't make sense to me.

Use a pipeline resource in your YAML to reference the other pipeline. You get this behavior automatically. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops

Hi @SterlingChargois, Have you got a chance to check my answer below to use pipeline resource or evaluate variable defined at compile time? Hope it can resolve your issue in this post. Thx for your time and sharing.

Hi @AlvinZhao-MSFT I did see your answer. I figured it out with another method. My pipeline was already build using the Azure DevOps UI, so I can't really alter the YAML file directly. I ended up doing two steps. One to grab the latest and one to grab the ID variable. Then I used a 'condition: eq( variables.artifactBuildId, '')' to choose which step to run.

Hi @SterlingChargois, Thank you very much for your taking time to share the update. It seemed that the variable artifactBuildId was generated during pipeline runtime rather than compile time; thus, the compile time conditional insertions which were processed before runtime didn't work for you. I have updated the answer with your option as well and hope it may helps others with similar concerns. Cheers.

As suggested by @DanielMann, you don't have to use a variable to control the artifact version to be downloaded. We can leverage the pipeline resource(s) instead.
Taking the sample YAML pipeline below for example, by default, it will download the latest version of the artifacts published by the UpstreamPipelineA, UNLESS you manually select the build before running this pipeline.
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: PiplineResourceA # Pipeline resource symbolic name
    source: UpstreamPipelineA  # Actual resource pipeline name

steps:
- download: PiplineResourceA


You haven't shared how your variable artifactBuildId is defined currently. If you have to evaluate a variable in conditional insertions (${{if}} ${{else}}) to decide which artifact version to be downloaded, you need to make sure it has a value at compile time. Here is a sample for your reference.
variables:
  artifactBuildId: ''

steps:
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: 'TheProjectName'
    definition: 'UpstreamPipelineA'
    ${{ if eq( variables.artifactBuildId, '') }}:
      buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    ${{ else }}:
      buildVersionToDownload: 'specific'
      pipelineId: '${{variables.artifactBuildId}}'
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'

Based on the further discussions, the variable artifactBuildId seemed be generated during pipeline runtime; however, the evaluation of your conditional insertions (${{if}} and ${{else}} ) were processed at compile time before runtime, which could result in the unexpected evaluation for such expressions. For this, we can opt to evaluate the runtime variable value in the condition property of the tasks.
- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: 'TheProjectName'
    definition: 'UpstreamPipelineA'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'latest'
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
  condition: eq( variables.artifactBuildId, '' )

- task: DownloadPipelineArtifact@2
  inputs:
    buildType: 'specific'
    project: 'TheProjectName'
    definition: 'UpstreamPipelineA'
    buildVersionToDownload: 'specific'
    pipelineId: '$(artifactBuildId)'
    targetPath: '$(Pipeline.Workspace)'
  condition: ne( variables.artifactBuildId, '' )


it is not '$(artifactBuildId)'. it should be $(resources.pipeline.PiplineResourceA .runID)
